# How can we prove Sylvester's determinant identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Sylvester's determinant identity states that if $A$ and $B$ are matrices of sizes $m\times n$ and $n\times m$, then

$$ \det(I_m+AB) = \det(I_n+BA)$$

where $I_m$ and $I_n$ denote the $m \times m$ and $n \times n$ identity matrices, respectively.

Could you sketch a proof for me, or point to an accessible reference?

Comment: See also http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/matrix-identities-as-derivatives-of-determinant-identities/

Comment: The identity is ${ x = 1 }$ case of [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/311362/303300).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ Work *universally*, i.e. consider the matrix entries as *indeterminates* $\:\!\rm a_{\:\!ij},b_{\:\!ij}.\,$ Adjoin them to $\,\Bbb Z\,$ to get the polynomial ring $\rm R = \mathbb Z[a_{\:\!ij},b_{\:\!ij}].\, $ In this polynomial ring $\rm R,$  compute the determinant of $\rm\, (1+A B) A = A (1+BA)\,$ then cancel the *nonzero polynomial* $\rm\, det(A)\, $ (valid by $\rm R$  a domain). $ $ Extend to non-square matrices by padding appropriately with $0$'s and $1$'s to get square matrices. Note that the proof is *purely* algebraic - it does not require any topological notions (e.g. density).

---

**Alternatively** we may employ Schur decomposition as follows

$$\rm\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \rm A \\
\rm B & 1 \end{array} \right]\, =\, \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \rm 0 \\
\rm B & 1 \end{array} \right]\ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \rm 0 \\
\rm 0 & \rm 1\!-\!BA \end{array} \right]\ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \rm A \\
\rm 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]\qquad$$

$$\rm\phantom{\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \rm B \\
\rm A & 1 \end{array} \right]}\, =\, \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \rm A \\
\rm 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]\ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\rm 1\!-\!AB & \rm 0 \\
\rm 0 & \rm 1 \end{array} \right]\ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \rm 0 \\
\rm B & 1 \end{array} \right]\qquad$$

---

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/98365/242) for more on universality of polynomial identities, *universal* cancellation (before evaluation) and closely relation topics, and see also [this sci.math thread](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/IAkwxntGerw/m/l4IUzagb71oJ) on 9 Nov 2007.

Comment: "simply pad-up appropriately with 0's and 1's to get square matrices." Oh, I can't believe it! Very nice! Many thanks.

Comment: There is rarely *need* for anything... For example, there is no need for proofs to be *purely algebraic* :)

Comment: @Mariano: It's a shining example of the power of universal proofs - which deserves emphasis (esp. since this simple algebraic proof is often overlooked - even by some professional mathematicians).

Comment: "Schur decomposition" typically refers to [Schur upper triangularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition); it might be clearer to say that you are employing "the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement)".

Comment: @BruceGeorge How to extend non-square matrices by padding with 0 and 1?

Answer (score 30):

**(1)** Start, for fun, with a silly proof for square matrices:

If $A$ is invertible, then 
$$
  \det(I+AB)=\det A^{-1}\cdot\det(I+AB)\cdot\det A=\det(A^{-1}\cdot(I+AB)\cdot A)=\det(I+BA).
$$ Now, in general, both $\det(I+AB)$ and $\det(I+BA)$ are continuous functions of $A$, and equal on the dense set where $A$ is invertible, so they are everywhere equal.

**(1)** Now, more seriously:

$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}I&-B\\\\A&I\end{pmatrix}
\det\begin{pmatrix}I&B\\\\0&I\end{pmatrix}
=\det\begin{pmatrix}I&-B\\\\A&I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}I&B\\\\0&I\end{pmatrix}
=\det\begin{pmatrix}I&0\\\\A&AB+I\end{pmatrix}
=\det(I+AB)
$$

and

$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}I&B\\\\0&I\end{pmatrix}
\det\begin{pmatrix}I&-B\\\\A&I\end{pmatrix}
=\det\begin{pmatrix}I&B\\\\0&I\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}I&-B\\\\A&I\end{pmatrix}
=\det\begin{pmatrix}I+BA&0\\\\A&I\end{pmatrix}
=\det(I+BA)
$$

Since the leftmost members of these two equalities are equal, we get the equality you want.

Comment: Nice argument. I guess this is very close to the "Schur decomposition" method suggested by Professor Dubuque.

Comment: @Bruce, for the non-square situation you can argue similarly to the first part by using the fact that surjections $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$, when $n\geq m$, are dense in the set of all matrices.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Are you sure about the surjection argument? We still can't make sense of $\det A$ when $A$ is not square.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I can't see the equality, could u explain?

Answer (score 12):

We will calculate $\det\begin{pmatrix} I_m & -A \\ B & I_n \end{pmatrix}$ in two different ways. We have 
$$ \det\begin{pmatrix} I_m & -A \\ B & I_n \end{pmatrix} 
  = \det\begin{pmatrix} I_m & 0 \\ B & I_n + BA \end{pmatrix} = \det(I_n + BA). $$
On the other hand, 
$$ \det\begin{pmatrix} I_m & -A \\ B & I_n \end{pmatrix} 
  = \det\begin{pmatrix} I_m+AB & 0 \\ B & I_n  \end{pmatrix} = \det(I_m + AB). $$

Comment: Maybe it's useful to show *why* you can do like that, that is, by multiplying on the right or on the left by the determinant $1$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix}I_m & A\\ 0 & I_n\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: What exactly is that determinant? Its elements are matrices itself?

Comment: As I mentioned in [my post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/17837/242) in the lnked dupe, this is a special case of Schur decomposition.

Answer (score 2):

here is another proof of $det(1 + AB) = det(1+BA).$ We will use the fact that 
the nonzero eigen values of $AB$ and $BA$ are the same and the determinant of a matrix is product of its eigenvalues. Take an eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 0$ of $AB$ and the coresponding eigenvector $x \neq 0.$ It is claimed that $y = Bx$ is an eigenvector of $BA$ corresponding to the same eignevalue $\lambda.$
For 
$ABx = Ay = \lambda x \neq 0,$  therefore $y \neq 0.$ Now we compute $BAy = B(ABx) = B(\lambda x) = \lambda y.$  We are done with the proof.

Comment: You need to show further that a  non-zero eigenvalue has the same algebraic multiplicity for both $AB$ and $BA$. Only after that can you conclude the proof.