# For $A, B$ $n\times n$ complex matrices, does $(AB)^n=0$ imply $(BA)^n=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non-commuting matrices and nilpotence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147730/non-commuting-matrices-and-nilpotence)

For $A, B$ $n\times n$ complex matrices, does $(AB)^n=0$ imply $(BA)^n=0$

I had this "proof or counterexample question". Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: hmm, maybe Jordan form can be of use ? (just an idea, nothing solid...)

Comment: [This is a repeat](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/147730/742).