# Is there a name referring to this result?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

For any real $m \times n$ matrix $A$, it seems that
$$\det(I_n + A^{T}A) = \det(I_m + AA^{T}) $$
always holds, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of size $n$.

Though I have not tried to prove this yet, I'm sure it is a part of well-known results in linear algebra. So my question is, what is the name referring to this fact, and where can I find a reference to it?

Comment: @MTurgeon: My question came from preliminary differential geometry, when considering the Riemannian volume form $\sqrt{g}$ of the metric on a graph of a multivariable function.

Comment: I thought at first that there was no reason for it to have a name. But then I noticed it was familiar, thus my answer below. So I was wrong.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/sylvesters-determinant-identity) for proofs of Sylvester's determinant identity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does: it is a special case of [Sylvester's determinant theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem).

Comment: Surely this is what I've been looking for! Thanks so much!