# Is this determinant identity correct?

Tags: matrices, determinant

For complex valued matrices $A,B$ where $B$ is invertible, does $$\det(I+B^{-1}AA^*)=\det(I+AA^*B^{-1})=\det(I+AB^{-1}A^*)=\det(I+A^*B^{-1}A)?$$
Here $A^*$ is the conjugate transform. I guess $\det(I+B^{-1}AA^*)=\det(I+AA^*B^{-1})$ holds by [Sylvester's identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/sylvesters-determinant-identity).

**Correction**
$$\det(I+B^{-1}AA^*)=\det(I+AA^*B^{-1})=\det(I+A^*B^{-1}A)?$$

Comment: I'm just now learning about Sylvester's identity, but doesn't the 2nd equality hold from letting $A = (A^*B^{-1})$ and $B = A$ in Sylvester's identity?  And similarly for the last.

Comment: Do you mean the last expression $\det(I+A^{*}B^{-1}A)$?

Comment: I updated my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Yes that gives the first two and the fourth. Third still seems incorrect.

Comment: It shows $\det(I + A^*B^{-1}A) = \det(I + B^{-1}AA^*) = \det(I + AB^{-1}A^*)$ from the equality above.

Comment: I guess not it shows $\det(I+B^{-1}AA^*)=\det(I+A^*B^{-1}A)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, $\det(I+B^{-1}AA^*)=\det(I+AA^*B^{-1})$ holds by Sylvester's Identity.

The other equalities don't hold. Let 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1/2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
\det(I+AB^{-1}A^*)=3, \ \ \det(I+A^*B^{-1}A)=2.
$$

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that $\det(I + B^{-1}AA^*) = 1$ in this case and hence doesn't necessarily equal either of the other two quantities as well.

Comment: @breeden: I think that $\det(I+B^{-1}AA^*)=2$.

Comment: I had to remind myself.  $A^*$ means replace every entry by its conjugate.  In this case (or any real case) $A^* = A$, right?

Comment: @MartinArgerami The problem arose by the different mutual information defined by authors in the following two papers. So they both can't be right? http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.217.4812&rep=rep1&type=pdf eq (5) and http://userver.ftw.at/~zemen/Cooperative/Lecture_12_handout.pdf eq (1) page 20.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Doesn't $\det(I+AA^*B^{-1})=\det(I+A^{*}B^{-1}A)$? Meaning first is equal to fourth? By Sylvester's

Comment: @breeden: $A^*$ means the transpose conjugate.

Comment: @triomphe: yes. Either that way, or calculating directly, the other two determinants equal to $2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align*}
\det(I + B^{-1}AA^*) &= \det(B)\det(I + B^{-1}AA^*)\det(B^{-1}) \\
&= \det(B(I + B^{-1}AA^*)B^{-1}) \\
&= \det(BB^{-1} + BB^{-1}AA^*B^{-1}) \\
&= \det(I + AA^*B^{-1})
\end{align*}$

That shows the first equality.  I don't see why the other two should be correct.  I only mention this because the identity is much easier than Sylvester's identity.

Sylvester's identity says

$$\det(I + CD) = \det(I + DC)$$

Letting $C = A^*B^{-1}$ and $D  = A$ we get

$$\det(I + A^*B^{-1}A) = \det(I + AA^*B^{-1}).$$

Similarly, if we let $C = B^{-1}A$ and $D = A^*$ we get

$$\det(I + B^{-1}AA^*) = \det(I + A^*B^{-1}A).$$

Comment: Bah, I give up.  Linear algebra is hard. :P