# Linear algebra proof regarding matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I'd like a hint rather than a full solution.

The problem I am considering is the following:

> $X$ is an $n\times m$ matrix $Y$ is $m\times n$
>
> Show that
>
> $(I - XY)^{-1}\cdot X = X\cdot(I - YX)^{-1}$

The first $I$ is of dimension $n$ and the second $I$ is of dimension $m$.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

Verify that
$$(I-XY)X=X(I-YX)$$

Comment: Okay....this is easy enough to verify. Am I now trying to work backwards from here or am I going about this the wrong way.

Comment: +1 great hint. A quick question: is the invertibility of $I-XY$ equivalent to that of $I-YX$?

Comment: I wonder if it would be a better hint to flip the sides of the equation.

Comment: I'm still having trouble making the leap from verifying the above equation to the one in the OP

Comment: @KimJongUn Invertibility of $I-XY$ is equivalent to $1$ not being an eigenvalue of $XY$; but $XY$ and $YX$ have the same non zero eigenvalues.

Comment: @KimJongUn See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/how-can-we-prove-sylvesters-determinant-identit