# How to prove this identity involving characteristic polynomials on both sides?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A\in \Bbb C^{m\times n},B\in \Bbb C^{n\times m},m\ge n$, prove:
$$\det(\lambda I_m-AB)=\lambda^{m-n}\det(\lambda I_n-BA)$$
I don't want to get into nasty determinant calculation. Instead, I think comparing the polynomial factors on both sides might help.  My attempt so far shows that $AB$ and $BA$ share the same **non-zero** eigenvalues, and that if $BA$ has 0 as eigenvalue, so does $AB$. I guess I'm on the right track but I can't proceed.  The multiplicities of $(\lambda-\lambda_i)$s on both sides seem to be big trouble. I cannot prove they are equal.  Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're basically only missing a proof that the multiplicities for the nonzero $\lambda_i$ are the same and for $\lambda = 0$ they are off by the constant $m-n$, right?

Comment: @AlexR yes this part seems hard

Comment: Already [answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/311362/1551) by Maisam Hedyelloo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sylvester's determinant identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/sylvesters-determinant-identity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the following could be caracterized as "nasty determinant calculation". I don't know how one can prove the equality without indulging in some computation.

Let $r=\operatorname{rank}(A)$

From a well-known theorem, derive that there exists $P,Q$ invertible $m\times m$ and $n \times n$ matrices such that $$A=P\begin{bmatrix}I_r& 0\\ 0 &0\end{bmatrix}Q $$

where $I_r$ denotes the $r\times r$ identity matrix.

By changes of basis, $$B=Q^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}E& F\\ G &H\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}$$

For some submatrices $E,F,G,H$.

---

Note that $AB=P\begin{bmatrix}E& F\\  0&0\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}$ and $BA=Q^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}E& 0\\  G&0\end{bmatrix}Q$.

Hence $\chi_{AB}:=\det(XI_m-AB)=\det(XI_r-E)(X)^{m-r}$ and  $\chi_{BA}:=\det(XI_n-BA)\det(XI_r-E)(X)^{n-r}$

Hence $\chi_{BA}=(X)^{n-m}\chi_{AB}$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm still a bit confused. What do you mean by "change of basis" and how do you get B?

Comment: Oh sorry.  Just got it. I was being stupid .... Brilliant answer!

Comment: One more question, how do you get $\chi (AB)$ and $\chi (BA)$?

Comment: I define $\chi_{AB}:=\det(XI_m-AB)$, and compute $\det(XI_m-AB)$ provided $XI_m-AB$ is similar to an upper triangular block matrix. The same argument applies to $\chi_{BA}$.

Comment: alright. Got that.

Comment: @Vim I have a personal question, I hope you don't mind. Are you a college student, if so, in which country are you studying ?

Comment: I'm a freshman and has determined to transfer my major to mathematics the next semester. I'm currently studying at Fudan University, Shanghai, China. I'm sorry that my algebra knowledge is quite weak so the questions I have made may seem a bit stupid. Anyhow I'm trying my best to catch up. And btw how about you, prof? I guess  you come from France?

Comment: I'm impressed by the quality of your questions (I enjoyed reading and thinking about every of them), and by your mastery of English as well. I'm an undergraduate studying mainly math and physics in Paris. I like to crack math problems.

Comment: Oh... I am so flattered.  Thanks!  Also I'm very impressed by you.  I think you have answered or commented on one or two questions I asked on this site. You (and many other guys)  provided superb answers for me which were truly truly inspiring and helpful! Just hope that one day I can also be a helper like you on this euthusiast site. I embrace this way of self-actualisation :-)