# Sylvester's determinant identity proof problems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

So I was stuck with the famous  Sylvester's determinant identity and don't know how to correctly interpret the difference between the sizes of identity matrices $I_m$ and $I_n$. The line that I dont' understand is:
$$\det(I_m) \det(I_n - B I_m^{-1} (-A)) = \det(I_n + BA).$$

I understand that $\det(I_m) = 1$ but what if we rewrite it in the form:
$$\det(I_m) \det(I_n - B I_m^{-1} (-A)) =  \det(I_mI_n - B I_m I_m^{-1} (-A)).$$

Do we have any right to multipy $I_m$ by $I_n$? Maybe there is a special property of matrix block determinants? Which part am I missing?

Comment: $BI^{-1}(-A)=-BA$.

Comment: I know that. But what about the $I_mI_n$ part?

Comment: You are right; that doesn't make sense. Why on earth would anyone do that?

Comment: How can you then explain the line in the Sylvester's determinant identity? I know that $\det\begin{pmatrix}I_m& -A\\ B& I_n\end{pmatrix} = \det(I_m I_n - B I_m I_m^{-1} (-A))$ but that doesn't make any sense for me.

Comment: The line you claim you "don't understand" is $$\det(I_m) \det(I_n - B I_m^{-1} (-A)) = \det(I_n + BA).$$ Since $\det I_m=1$, the left side is $\det(I_n - B I_m^{-1} (-A))$, and since $I_n - B I_m^{-1} (-A) = I_n + BA$, then that equals $\det(I_n + BA)$.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the question you asked was not the question you really intended to ask. Consider
$$\pmatrix{I_m&-A\\B&I_n}=\pmatrix{I_m&O\\B&I_n}\pmatrix{I_m&O\\O&I_n+BA}
\pmatrix{I_m&-A\\O&I_n}.$$
Take determinants. As two of three matrices on the right are triangular 
with $1$s on the diagonal, they have determinant $1$. Thus
$$\det\pmatrix{I_m&-A\\B&I_n}=\det\pmatrix{I_m&O\\O&I_n+BA}.$$
But that's a block diagonal matrix, with determinant $\det (I_n)\det(I_n+BA)
=\det(I_n+BA)$.

Comment: This *Schur decomposition* is already mentioned in a [7-year old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17837/242) on this topic.