# Matrix proof : Show that if I − ED is nonsingular, then I − DE is nonsingular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I is the identity matrix.

Let D ∈ $R^{n\times m}$ and E ∈ $R^{m\times n}$

Show that if I − ED is nonsingular, then I − DE is nonsingular
and

$(I − DE)^{−1} = I + D(I − ED)^{−1}E$

i don't get how to this first of all i don't get how i could show the first proof. Because DE and ED are different dimensions i don't get how to you could ever compare them.

Second i dont get how to show that the equation is true because the I-ED is inbetween the E and D and with matrices you can't just multiple in any order i thought so i don't get how to get rid of it.

Comment: This is a consequence of $\det(I-DE)=\det(I-ED)$ which is known as Sylvester's identity,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17831

Answer (score 2):

Compute the product of the matrix $I-DE$  and its wannabe inverse  $I+D(I-ED)^{-1}E$:
$$
(I+D(I-ED)^{-1}E)(I-DE)=I-DE + D(I-ED)^{-1}E(I-DE)\\=I-DE + D(I-ED)^{-1}(I-ED)E=I-DE+DE=I.
$$
The product is the identity, which proves the claim.

Answer (score 1):

We can show that $I-DE$ is nonsingular by contradiction. If it is singular, there is a vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$ (I-DE) v = 0 .$$
Consider $w = E v\in\mathbb{R}^m$.
$$(I-ED)w = E v - EDE v = E (I-DE) v = 0$$
so $I-ED$ is also singular (contradiction). Therefore, $I-DE$ is not singular.

The form of the inverse is verified with simple matrix algebra, see [daw's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3009259/149246).