# Prove $\det(I_m + AB) = \det(I_n + BA)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

$A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n\times m$ matrix. 
$$
\det(I_m + AB) = \det(I_n + BA)
$$
Solution:
I found this guys:
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}I&-B\\\\A&I\end{pmatrix}
\det\begin{pmatrix}I&B\\\\0&I\end{pmatrix}
=\det\begin{pmatrix}I&-B\\\\A&I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}I&B\\\\0&I\end{pmatrix}
=\det\begin{pmatrix}I&0\\\\A&AB+I\end{pmatrix}
=\det(I+AB)
$$

and

$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}I&B\\\\0&I\end{pmatrix}
\det\begin{pmatrix}I&-B\\\\A&I\end{pmatrix}
=\det\begin{pmatrix}I&B\\\\0&I\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}I&-B\\\\A&I\end{pmatrix}
=\det\begin{pmatrix}I+BA&0\\\\A&I\end{pmatrix}
=\det(I+BA)
$$

Source:
[Sylvester's determinant identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/sylvesters-determinant-identity)

Comment: @RobertIsrael: This doesn't look like a duplicate to me.

Comment: Though it's certainly related, and might lead to a conjecture such as: if $m < n$, then the characteristic polynomial of $BA$ is $\lambda^{n - m}$ times the characteristic polynomial of $AB$.  Then, you might even be able to prove such a conjecture by using the "well, it's true in a generic case where $AB$ has all eigenvalues of multiplicity 1, and the coefficients of both sides are polynomials in $a_{ij}, b_{ij}$, so..." type of argument.

Comment: Quite a standard proof on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity)

Comment: Since the $I$ on the left side and the $I$ on the right side are different matrices, it would be a good idea to write $I_m$ and $I_n$ or similar.

Comment: Closely related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311342/do-ab-and-ba-have-same-minimal-and-characteristic-polynomials

Comment: Why does $\det\begin{pmatrix}I&0\\\\A&AB+I\end{pmatrix}
=\det(I+AB)$?

Answer (score 0):

If $B$ is (square and) invertible, then
\begin{align*}
\det (1 + AB) = \det \left[B^{-1}(1 + BA)B\right] = (\det B^{-1}) \det(1 + BA)\det B) = \det (1 + BA).
\end{align*}
But $f(A, B) = \det (1 + AB) - \det (1 + BA)$ is a polynomial in the entries $A_{ij}$ and $B_{ij}$, and the space of invertible $B$ is dense (as if $B$ is not invertible, then $B + \epsilon $ is invertible for small $\epsilon > 0$). Hence $f(A, B)$ vanishes everywhere, as required. For the arbitrary case, pad $A$ and $B$ with $0$s and reduce to the square case.

(That's assuming that you're working over a ground field like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. To make the argument work in completely generality, you'll either need to be more precise about the nature of the "dense set," embed $A$ and $B$ in a larger $GL_n(k)$ as in the wiki link above, explicitly work with something like a $QR$-decomposition of $A$ and $B$, or etc.)

Comment: When $m\ne n$, when is an $n\times m$ matrix invertible?

Comment: @celtschk: Never, of course, but you can pad $A$ and $B$ out with $0$s and apply the same argument. (I could have sworn there was a similar or identical question posted a while back, but I can't seem to find it.)

Comment: Another way to make the argument work in complete generality is to observe that both sides are defined for $A \in M_{m\times n}(R), B \in M_{n\times m}(R)$ for *any* commutative ring $R$, and they're functorial.  So, from truth for $R = \mathbb{C}$, you can conclude truth in $R = \mathbb{Z}[a_{ij}, b_{ij}]$, from which truth for $R$ any commutative ring follows.

Comment: Hmm, still can't seem to find it. This is the closest match I could find: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/sylvesters-determinant-identity . The idea in short is that it's easy to prove for invertible (and thus square) matrices; then for square matrices by continuity; then for arbitrary matrices by padding with $0$s and being more careful than I am here.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: That's probably the cleanest way of doing it.