# To prove:- $|AB-I|+|BA-I| =0$ given that $A$ is any $3\times 2$ matrix and $B$ is any $2\times 3$ matrix.

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, algebra-precalculus, determinant

I was just told that for any given matrix if it is $n\times (n-1)$ and another of $(n-1)\times n$ then also the above kind of situation that is $$\det(AB-I)+\det(BA-I)=0,$$ where $I$ is the corresponding identity matrix of the square matrix so formed.

Also in order to prove it I tried to solve it by any theorem that I know or so but was unable.

So, I checked it for any random matrix with random variable and calculated the same thing via a matrix calculator, and shockingly it was correct.

I searched it on internet and was unable to find any explanation.
So, I eventually turned to stack exchange.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If you look at the answer given below, you'll also see there's nothing special about $n \times (n-1)$ and $(n-1) \times n$ matrices.  The only requirement is that the matrices be $m\times n$ and $n\times m$ where $m$ is odd and $n$ is even.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
\det(AB-I_3) &= (-1)^3\det(I_3 - AB)\\
&= - \det(I_2 - BA)\\
&= - (-1)^2 \det(BA-I_2)
\end{align}

The second equality holds due to [Sylvester determinant identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2084585/306553).

In general, if $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, then we have

$$\det(AB-I_m) = (-1)^{n+m} \det(BA-I_n)= (-1)^{n+m \pmod{2}} \det(BA-I_n)$$