# Prove that $\det(VH'BH+I_n)=\det(BHVH'+I_p)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am trying to prove that two determinants are equal. I've come quite far, but I do not know how to proceed and I cannot find any relevant properties. They contain the same matrices, but in a different ordering. Let $V$ be a $n\times n$ matrix, $H$ a $p\times n$ matrix, $H'$ its transpose, and $B$ a $p\times p$matrix:

$$\det(VH'BH+I_n)=\det(BHVH'+I_p)$$

Good references are also very welcome! I am currently mostly using the matrix cookbook.

Comment: What does $H'$ indicate? Is it the inverse? Are (some of) these matrices invertible?

Comment: H' indicates the transpose of H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C=VH'$ and $D=BH.$ You want to prove $$\det(CD+I_n)=\det(DC+I_p).$$

This is the well-known [Sylvester determinant identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/how-can-we-prove-sylvesters-determinant-identity).